# Is there any way to generate HRV records at particular Interval using own watch app?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to generate HRV records at respective duration, let's say every 15 Minutes. I want to generate programmatically / forcefully HRV records using my own watch app. Please note that, I want to keep HRV generate functionality within my app.

**I know the Way to get HRV data from the Health kit BUT I want to write/generate HRV data using my app. HRV functionality resides in my app.**

**As per my research, default Watch Breath app is able to generate HRV records. It will create a mindful session and generate HRV. Can I implement the same functionality in My app?**

Please share your valuable thoughts.

Thanks in Advance... Happy Coding :)